# how to write a function that takes a list of names and return the oldest name?

Tags: node.js, api

1. Get the oldest name from the given name list.
   Example:
   list = ["Tom","Jim","Kerry","John"]
2. Given below API to get the age of one name:
   GET [https://api.agify.io/?name={name}](https://api.agify.io/?name=%7Bname%7D)
3. Response format: {"name":"dawei","age":54,"count":143}

Task is to Write a function in node.js to take a list of names and return the oldest name

I have written the code below-

```
function getOldest(list){
  let oldest;
  let listOfPromises = list.map((name) => {
    callAPI(name);
  });
  
  let resp = [];
  Promise.all([listOfPromises]).then(function (resArr) {
    resp = resArr;
  }, function (err) {
     throw err;
  })

  resp.sort((a, b) => {
    a.age > b.age;
  })
  oldest = resp[0].name;
    
  return  oldest
}

function callAPI(name) {
  let url = `https://api.agify.io/?name=${name}`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(body.data);
      }
    })
  })
}

let list = ["Tom", "Jim", "Kerry", "John"];
getOldest(list);
}
```

Is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Just copy/pasting your assignments will not win you any friends.

Comment: On the fourth line I think you might have intended to return the promise inside of the callback for the map function `callAPI(name)`. Otherwise `Promise.all([listOfPromises])` will not evaluate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't cover repeted values

```
const arrayOfNames = [
  {
    name: "Alice",
    age: 40,
    count: 120238
  },
  {
    name: "Damian",
    age: 70,
    count: 120238
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    age: 60,
    count: 120238
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 30,
    count: 120238
  }
];

const getOldestName = (names) => {
  const ages= [];
  for (let name of names) {
    ages.push(name.age);
  }
  const highestAge = Math.max(...ages);
  return names.find((element) => element.age === highestAge);
};
console.log(getOldestName(arrayOfNames));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.